# trying to import an image in react

Tags: reactjs

I'm just trying to import a png onto a navbar but I keep getting errors.

```
import React from "react";
import { Nav, NavLink, Bars, NavMenu } from "./navBarComponent";
import logo-light from "../logo-light.png";

const Navbar = () => {
return (
 <>
<Nav>
 <NavLink to="/">
<img src={"logo-light"} alt="logo" />
</NavLink>
<Bars />
<NavMenu>
<NavLink to="/ourcompany">Our Company</NavLink>
<NavLink to="/contact">Contact</NavLink>
<NavLink to="/locations">Locations</NavLink>
</NavMenu>
</Nav>
 </>
);
};

export default Navbar;
```

in vs code the "import logo-light from" part has red error lines under it. when I hover it says 'import... =' can only be used in typescript files.
in the console it says:

[image]

I've tried moving the image to public, renaming the image, etc but nothing seems to work.  what am I doing wrong?

Comment: just src="../logo-light.png"

Comment: doing that and removing the import does make the errors go away but no image shows up on the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to write the same name as the filename You can use an alias name you want and import that directly in the src like below

```js
   
import logolight from "../logo-light.png";

<img src={logolight} alt="logo" />
```

Comment: now it says module not found, can't resolve

Comment: I think the image is not found on current path

Comment: ahh yeah you're right. I moved it to a different folder and it works now. thank you